# How to Sign-in Users with OAuth Tokens

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, oauth-2.0, asp.net-core-mvc

I am building an ASP.NET Core MVC web application that has two ways of authenticating; one way uses `.AddOpenIdConnect()` and is already working.

The second way is to retrieve OAuth tokens from a web service.

```
// MVC
public async Task<IActionResult> GetToken()
{
    var tokenResponse = await _tokenService.GetToken();

    // This header did not appear in the JwtBearerEvents
    string headerValue = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", tokenResponse.AccessToken).ToString();
    Request.Headers.Authorization = headerValue;

    return RedirectToAction("ShowToken", "Account");
}

// This AuthorizeAttribute causes JwtBearerEvents to fire
[Authorize(AuthenticationSchemes = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)]
public IActionResult ShowToken()
{    
    return View();
}
```

After retrieving tokens from a web service,

1. How do I pass the the OAuth tokens to the authentication middleware?  (I already tried setting the authorization header, but that didn't work.)
2. How do I configure the authentication middleware to handle them?

```
builder.Services.AddAuthentication(options =>
{
    options.DefaultScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;

    options.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
    options.DefaultSignInScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
    options.DefaultSignOutScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;

    options.DefaultChallengeScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme; 
})
.AddJwtBearer(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme, options =>
{
    options.TokenHandlers.Add(new StrictTokenHandler());
    options.TokenValidationParameters = tokenValidationParameters;
    options.SaveToken = true;
    options.Events = new JwtBearerEvents
    {
        OnMessageReceived = context =>
        {
            var p = context.Properties;
            // context.Token = <context does not contain token>                        
            return Task.CompletedTask;
        },
        OnChallenge = context =>
        {
            var p = context.Properties;
            // have token, but can't set Token
            return Task.CompletedTask;
        },
        OnTokenValidated = context =>
        {
            return Task.CompletedTask;
        },
    };
})
.AddCookie(options =>
{
    options.LoginPath = new PathString("/Account/Login");
})
.AddOpenIdConnect(options =>
{
    options.Authority = issuer;
    // the rest omitted for brevity
    // this is working
});
```

In the `.AddJwtBearer()` method above, the context `MessageReceivedContext` has a settable `Token` property, but I don't have it yet.  The `OnChallenge` event has the token if I set it in `AuthenticationProperties`, but `JwtBearerChallengeContext` does not have a settable `Token` property.

This is the token information returned from the token service.  How do I get this into the Authentication middleware?

[image: Token Information Screenshot]

Comment: To sign-in users with OAuth tokens from a separate service in your ASP.NET Core MVC app, define `TokenValidationParameters` for token evaluation and register a new `AddJwtBearer` scheme named "oauth". Then, retrieve the token from your /token service and call `HttpContext.SignInAsync("oauth")` with the token to trigger validation and sign-in.  In addition, remember to customize scheme names, handle events, and ensure secure token validation practice. Please [`refer to this official document`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/cookie?view=aspnetcore-8.0).

Comment: @MdFaridUddinKiron, how do I call .SignInAsync() with the token?  I don't see any overload or authentication properties that do that.

Comment: Maybe I am going about this all wrong.  If so, please suggest.  NOTE: The retrieval of the tokens via a web service is a requirement, but anything after that is fair game.

Comment: I think the weird thing here is that the Token is issued in one application (web api) and validated in a different application (your mvc app). That isn't normal. Can anybody call the GetToken() endpoint in your app, or are you passing auth information to the web api to get a token? Ideally, the reason that somebody is allowed to obtain a token should be the same reason they are authorized in your mvc app.

Comment: @thewallrus Thanks for the comment! =) There's obviously a lot of detail left out of the question, but to summarize... `GetToken()` is actually called `VerifyFactor()`, and it is part of a passwordless flow called "trusted account fingerprint".  (I didn't design the flow; I am following a spec.)  So, while it might not seem normal, it is necessary.  Interestingly, `VerifyFactor()` doesn't even mint the token.  Okta does.  The MVC application validates the expiration and the signature of the token, then passes it back to Okta's `/introspect` endpoint for final validation.  Cont.

Comment: @thewallrus Cont... So, technically, the token is minted AND validated by the same entity, Okta.  The app and intermediate service is a relying party and service provider.  There is another replying party that I haven't even mentioned, but that's not important here.

Comment: Web and mobile clients have very different best practces, due to the environments in which they run. Also, you are trying to use a cookie secured website as an API which is not right. Any kind of migration to OAuth shoild involve an update to an API architecture. That is the heart of how it works. Anyway, my last words on this one ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Original Answer**

I have found a <strike>solution</strike> **workaround** of sorts, however I am not yet convinced that it is the best solution, so I am going to leave the question unanswered until the bounty expires and accept the answer the seems best.  (I found a better solution.  See up
update below.)

The key seems to be to set the authorization header like this:

```
string accessToken = tokenResponse.AccessToken;
Request.Headers.Authorization = $"Bearer {accessToken}";
```

...right before calling `AuthenticateAsync()` like this:

```
var result = await HttpContext.AuthenticateAsync(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme);
```

### AccountController.cs

```
// MVC
public async Task<IActionResult> GetToken()
{
    var tokenResponse = await _tokenService.GetToken();

    // just for ShowToken - not required 
    TempData.Serialize("tokenInfo", new TokenViewModel()
    {
        TokenType = tokenResponse.TokenType,
        Expires = tokenResponse.Expires,
        AccessToken = tokenResponse.AccessToken,
        Scope = tokenResponse.Scope,
        RefreshToken = tokenResponse.RefreshToken,
        IdToken = tokenResponse.IdToken,
    });

    // this seems like a hack, but works - is there a better way?
    string accessToken = tokenResponse.AccessToken;
    Request.Headers.Authorization = $"Bearer {accessToken}";
    
    var result = await HttpContext.AuthenticateAsync(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme);

    if (result.Principal != null)
    {
        await HttpContext.SignInAsync(result.Principal);
        return RedirectToAction(nameof(AccountController.ShowToken), "Account");
    }
    else
    {
        return Challenge(
            new AuthenticationProperties { RedirectUri = Url.Action("Index", "Home") },
            OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme);
    }
}

[HttpGet]
[Authorize()]  // if not authorized, the fallback is the default, OIDC-Cookie auth
public IActionResult ShowToken()
{
    // Only for demonstration purposes
    var tokenViewModel = TempData.Deserialize<TokenViewModel>("tokenInfo");
    return View(tokenViewModel);
}
```

### Program.cs

```
services.AddAuthentication(options =>
{
    options.DefaultScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;

    options.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
    options.DefaultSignInScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
    options.DefaultSignOutScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;

    options.DefaultChallengeScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme; 
}).AddJwtBearer(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme, options =>
    {
        var httpClient = new HttpClient(new TestClientMessageHandler("starling-testclient", typeof(Program).Assembly.GetName().Version));
        var configurationManager = new ConfigurationManager<OpenIdConnectConfiguration>(
            issuer + "/.well-known/openid-configuration",
            new OpenIdConnectConfigurationRetriever(),
            new HttpDocumentRetriever(httpClient));
        var signingKeyProvider = new DiscoveryDocumentSigningKeyProvider(configurationManager);
        var tokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters()
        {
            ValidateIssuer = true,
            ValidIssuer = issuer,  // configured above

            ValidateAudience = true,
            ValidAudience = audience,  // configured above

            RequireSignedTokens = true,
            ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,
            IssuerSigningKeyResolver = (token, securityToken, keyId, validationParameters) =>
            {
                var signingKeys = signingKeyProvider.GetSigningKeysAsync().GetAwaiter().GetResult();
                return signingKeys.Where(x => x.KeyId == keyId);
            },
            NameClaimType = JwtRegisteredClaimNames.Name,

            RequireExpirationTime = true,
            ValidateLifetime = true,
            ClockSkew = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(2.0)
        };
        options.TokenHandlers.Add(new StrictTokenHandler());  // custom class, not required
        options.TokenValidationParameters = tokenValidationParameters;
        options.SaveToken = true;
        options.Events = new JwtBearerEvents
        {
            OnTokenValidated = context =>
            {
                var token = context.SecurityToken;
                Debug.Assert(token != null);
                
                var principal = context.Principal;                        
                Debug.Assert(principal?.Identity?.IsAuthenticated == true);   
                
                return Task.CompletedTask;
            }, 
        };
    })
    .AddCookie(options =>
    {
        options.LoginPath = new PathString("/Account/Login");
    })
    .AddOpenIdConnect(options =>
    {
        options.Authority = issuer;
        options.SaveTokens = true;
        
        // details omitted for brevity
    });
```

---

### UPDATE - Solution

After retrieving the token, simply read it and create a new authenticated ClaimsPrincipal like this:

```
var handler = new JwtSecurityTokenHandler();
var jwtSecurityToken = handler.ReadJwtToken(tokenResponse.AccessToken);
var identity = new ClaimsIdentity(jwtSecurityToken.Claims, "auth-type-token");
var principal = new ClaimsPrincipal(identity);
```

<sup>Note: It's important to set the `AuthenticationType` parameter when creating the `ClaimsIdentity`.  Otherwise, `IsAuthenticated` will be false.</sup>

After creating `ClaimsPrincipal`, call `SignInAsync()`:

```
await HttpContext.SignInAsync(principal);
```

At this point, a standard ASP.NET auth cookie is used.

Answer (score 1):

You can customize behavior by subclassing the [JwtBearerHandler](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/main/src/Security/Authentication/JwtBearer/src/JwtBearerHandler.cs) and overriding `HandleAuthenticateAsync`. This might involve doing your work to get the token, updating the request's HTTP Authorization header, then calling the base class. Or you can write a custom handler as in [this code of mine](https://github.com/gary-archer/oauth.apisample.netcore/blob/master/src/plumbing/middleware/CustomAuthenticationHandler.cs).

**SECURITY**

It is not clear from your question how the incoming call is secured though. Eg. the caller should provide the token. How is security being managed if the backend code itself gets tokens from a web service?

**SEPARATION**

Usually `AddJwtBearer` is used by a web API (aka resource server). Whereas `AddCookie` and `AddOpenIdConnect` are used by backend websites. A preferred way to separate these concerns is to split them into multiple components. The API can then be called by both web and mobile clients and uses a single authentication scheme in both cases:

- API
- Web client
- Mobile client

This will also keep code simpler. Otherwise you may struggle with areas like error handling:

- A cookie based website redirects unauthorized requests
- An API returns a 401 response

Comment: Thank you for your answer.  The web application backend is calling a Web API to get the token.  I have the token in a MVC controller action, but now I need the Jwt middleware to validate the token and set an auth cookie, like `AddOpenIdConnect()` does currently. (It's somewhat inverted, I know.  But it is a requirement in this case.)  I was able to get Jwt middleware to grab the token by setting `Request.Headers.Authorization = $"Bearer {accessToken}"` right before `HttpContext.ChallengeAsyc()`, but this seems a little hack-ish, doesn't it?  Is there a better way in this scenario?

Comment: Hmm. it might be easier to answer if you updated your question to include client behaviour in the end-to-end flow, which is usually a crucial part of the design.. This might enable me to suggest a standard solution that meets your needs. From the information so far I can only recommend slightly convoluted solutions. At the moment this would include overriding the [.NET cookie handler](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/main/src/Security/Authentication/Cookies/src/CookieAuthenticationHandler.cs) or writing a new one. Yet there may be more elegant designs ...

Comment: That's fair.  There is, of course, a lot more to the design. =) In a comment to @thewallrus on my OP I reveal some of the details.  In addition to that, the MVC client here is just a test client.  The REAL client will be a native mobile app, being developed by a well-known technology company that I am not allowed to reveal (NDA).  The MVC client is more of a proof of concept for demonstration purposes.  That said, it's still a good Q&A topic IMO.  Maybe the question should have been... "How do you inject an access token obtained out of band into the authentication middleware pipeline?"

Answer (score 1):

This looks like a good case to use [Custom Middleware](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/middleware/write?view=aspnetcore-8.0). This will run on all requests, so your conditionals might need to change. But after modifying the authoriztion header (is this secure?) in the middleware, it will still use your configured JWT bearer and cookie scheme. This would replace getting the token and modifying request headers in the controller. I'm not sure if you would have to manually sign-in a user at this point, but if you do, you could do that in the controller after manually checking/decoding the token.

Assuming your `TokenService` is registered in DI:

```
public class TokenInterceptMiddleware
{
    private readonly RequestDelegate _next;
    private readonly ITokenService _tokenService;

    public TokenInterceptMiddleware(RequestDelegate next, ITokenService tokenService)
    {
        _next = next;
        _tokenService = tokenService;
    }

    public async Task Invoke(HttpContext context)
    {        
        var token = _tokenService.GetToken();
        
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(context.Request.Headers["Authorization"]))
        {
            context.Request.Headers["Authorization"] = $"Bearer {token}";
        }

        await _next(context);
    }
}
```

Register your middleware. Order of registration matters.

**Program.cs**

```
app.UseMiddleware<TokenInterceptMiddleware>();
app.UseAuthentication();
app.UseAuthorization();
```

I appreciate the detail in your comments earlier. I would still question the ability of your MVC app to create an identity of a user based on separate service, but i don't really know the purpose of your app (nor do I need to know).

EDIT:
You can manually validate a bearer token.

```
    var mySecret = "mySecret";
    var mySecurityKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(mySecret));
    var tokenHandler = new JwtSecurityTokenHandler();
    var claimsPrincipal = tokenHandler.ValidateToken(token, new TokenValidationParameters
    {
        ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,
        ValidateIssuer = false,
        ValidateAudience = false,
        IssuerSigningKey = mySecurityKey
    }, out SecurityToken validatedToken);
    
    HttpContext.SignInAsync(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme, claimsPrincipal);
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer.  My application is receiving the token upon successful verification of a one-time passcode (issued by Okta, but returned by a custom service).  It is in the form of JSON response body.  So what I am doing currently is setting the Authorization header on the client, then calling HttpContext.AuthenticateAsync().  JwtBearer then handles the Authorization header.  The part that feels hack-ish is setting the header of a request that has already been received.

Comment: So don't set the authorization header.  You can manually validate the token and use whatever scheme you want. This is what the first comment (@Md Farid Uddin Kiron) was suggesting.

Comment: you may have missed my answer or some of my other comments.  The token is being returned from a service.  It's being returned to a controller action.  The crux of my OP was how to get this token into the middleware.  The best way that I have found so far is to set the Authorization header, and then call `HttpContext.AuthenticateAsync()`, where the `AddJwtBearer()` middleware will see the header and process it like it would in a Web API.  Do you know of a better way?  Your custom `TokenInterceptMiddleware` would require setting the Authorization header as well.

Comment: And you're right, @Md Farid Uddin Kiron did suggest something similar.  He/she said "call `HttpContext.SignInAsync("oauth")` with the token".  How do you call `SignInAsync()` with the token?  AuthenticationProperties?  I tried this, but it didn't work.  Strangely, the MessageReceived event, whose context allows setting the token, did not contain the access-token property that I set.  ‍♂️ What I am missing here?

Comment: @MarkGood, are you missing the order that asp.net core handles requests? 1) Request is received, 2) then middleware (which is usually routing and authentication and authorization) runs, 3) then controller stuff (model binding & actions). That is overly simplified, but if you obtain the token in the controller, the authentication middleware has already run and the token won't be used. My suggestion is to get the token in middleware. You don't have to set the authorization header during middleware, and you can call your `_tokenService.GetToken()` in the `OnMessageReceived` event

Comment: , and set the `context.Token` in that event as well.

Comment: Thank you for your comments.  I really do appreciate it.  =)  I left a lot of detail out of my question, trying not to detract from the real problem.  However, it seems that I over-simplified.  The MVC `GetToken()` action is actually [POST] `VerifyFactor(string otp)`, where a call is made to a downstream service to verify a one-time passcode.  If the OTP is valid, the service call returns an access-token.  It is at this point that I need to sign the user in.  I guess I could create the ClaimsPrincipal here and then call SignInAsync().  I'll give this some thought.  TY!

Answer (score 0):

You can set SaveToken in .AddJwtBearer() to true.

```
services.AddAuthentication()
    .AddJwtBearer(options =>
    {
        // your other config
        options.SaveToken = true;
    });
```

and get access token from HttpContext with GetTokenAsync method.

```
public class SampleController : Controller
{
    public void Index()
    {
        var accessToken = HttpContext.GetTokenAsync("access_token");
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm sorry my question wasn't clearer.  My application is retrieving tokens from a web service (scenario 2).  They're not in the authorization header.  I'll try to make the question more clear.